# Is it good practice in Android to implement our own back button rather than using device's backbutton

Tags: android

Is it good practice in Android to implement our own back button rather than using device's backbutton. May I know what are the disadvantages of using our own back button in Application rather than device provided one.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Using another back button is confusing. Do you have real reasons for wanting a second one in your app ?

Comment: Actually while moving from one activity to another activity I will kill previous activity in order to save memory. But when I want to go back to previous activity I will either use a back button on screen or override device's backbutton functionality using "onBackPressed()" in which I will create an intent and I will start activity freshly.Is this best practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it good practice in Android to implement our own back button rather than using device's backbutton.

Absolutely not.

> May I know what are the disadvantages of using our own back button in Application rather than device provided one.

1. Waste of screen space
2. Lack of design consistency with other Android apps

Comment: Actually while moving from one activity to another activity I will kill previous activity in order to save memory. But when I want to go back to previous activity I will either use a back button on screen or override device's backbutton functionality using "onBackPressed()" in which I will create an intent and I will start activity freshly.Is this best practice?

Comment: @Android_programmer_camera: "Is this best practice?" -- no. If there were such as thing as "worst practice", this might qualify.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Would you say it's bad practice even if it's a game? I've seen a lot of top class games that override the device back button so that it doesn't do anything. And of course they implement their own virtual back button.

Comment: @Emiam: Considering the complaints I have seen from users, yes, I'd say it is a bad practice. My guess is that some cross-platform game toolkits lack support for Android's BACK button and disable it.

Answer (score 1):

As a user myself, I find it intuitive to use the back button because it is in use in all major applications. Futhermore, I find that adding another back button to serve the same function is a waste of screen real estate (and this is usually something you like to spare).

Comment: Actually while moving from one activity to another activity I will kill previous activity in order to save memory. But when I want to go back to previous activity I will either use a back button on screen or override device's backbutton functionality using "onBackPressed()" in which I will create an intent and I will start activity freshly.Is this best practice?