# Add back button to action bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have been trying to add a back button to the action bar.

I want my view to look like this:
[image]

I want to add the back button in the left of the action bar.

I added this code

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `Up` button it not them same with `back` button. And i think add back button is [anti Android pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4735967/1050058)

Comment: The screenshot is of an iPhone. Android does not run on such devices. Android has its own back button, always available for the user; you do not need to put one in the action bar.

Comment: Many apps today (2014) put a back/up button in the actionbar (eg. Instagram) so I even if this is an antipattern.. It is clearly a need in users (maybe users going from iPhone see more benefit on this)

Comment: please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34413776/2826147)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

After setting 
`actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`

Add the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; goto parent activity.
            this.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a bit cavalier, you have to test that `menuItem == android.R.id.home` before taking that action (usually in a switch statement along with other options for that activity or fragment). For API >= 16, you can also simply [define the parent activity in the manifest](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html)

Comment: this crashed my android app

Comment: @slier, my app crashed too, and I found that actionbar was returning null

Comment: use `getSupportActionBar()` instead

Answer (score 55):

Add

```
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

and then add the following

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
{       
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }
}
```

As suggested by [naXa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1429387/naxa) I've added a check on the `itemId`, to have it work correctly in case there are multiple buttons on the action bar.

Comment: Where's a check that the selected option is Home button?

Comment: I'm not sure. You might ask a specific question about that! :)

Comment: I mean, if there are other options in menu (for example, Help) they will be handled by `onOptionsItemSelected()` too, so we need to check `menuItem.getItemId() == android.R.id.home`

Comment: You are right! Thanks for that... I'll fix immediately the code

Answer (score 27):

this one worked for me:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_your_activity);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    // ... other stuff
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
    finish();
    return true;
}
```

The method onSupportNavigateUp() is called when you use the back button in the SupportActionBar.

Answer (score 24):

After setting

```
 actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

You have to configure the parent activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" />
<activity
    android:name="com.example.SecondActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Look here for more information http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Comment: This the cleaner route. Also, good link to implementing from android.

Comment: I suspect this will not work if your child activity has more than one parent activity. i.e. more than one activity has the ability to navigate to the child activity.

Answer (score 10):

There are two ways to approach this.

**Option 1: Update the Android Manifest**
If the settings Activity is always called from the same activity, you can make the relationship in the Android Manifest. Android will automagically show the 'back' button in the ActionBar

```
<activity
    android:name=".SettingsActivity"
    android:label="Setting Activity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.example.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

**Option 2: Change a setting for the ActionBar**
If you don't know which Activity will call the Settings Activity, you can create it like this. First in your activity that extends ActionBarActivity (Make sure your @imports match the level of compatibility you are looking for).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings_test);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Then, detect the 'back button' press and tell Android to close the currently open Activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; goto parent activity.
            this.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

That should do it!

Answer (score 7):

Firstly Use this:

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Then set operation of button click in `onOptionsItemSelected` method

```
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
         finish();
        return true;
     default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
 }
```

Comment: is following should be there ?
`@Override

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }`

Comment: If you need options in menu then it should be, otherwise not important.

Comment: I am using AppCompatActivity, and onOptionsItemSelected is there  <br/>
but the case `case android.R.id.home:` does not get called , any hint ?

Comment: All Methods are Not working in My Case Because i  am using Fragment in

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to check `menuItem.getItemId()` against `android.R.id.home` in the `onOptionsItemSelected` method

Duplicate of [Android Sherlock ActionBar Up button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996664/android-sherlock-actionbar-up-button)

Answer (score 6):

Simpler and better:
For API >= 16

Simply add "parentActivityName" for each activity in Manifest. The back button will automatically take u to the parent activity.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
```

Comment: This doesn't work with me. It creates a back button on Actionbar and it goes to the parent Activity. But the parent Activity works nothing.

Comment: @c-an you can override the onOptionsItemSelected method and set onBackPressed for the itemId android.R.id.home

Answer (score 6):

Use this to show back button and move to previous activity,

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        assert actionBar != null;
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back_dark);


@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

if anyone else need the solution

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in onCreate() method

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

then Override this method

```
 @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
        finish();
        return true;
    }
```